# How do you create a Flutter App without the Counter MyApp boilerplate code being created?

Tags: flutter

Using `flutter create myapp` and File -> New Flutter Project... in Android Studio/IntelliJ both result in the sample code for MyApp (the increment counter app) being created. Is there a way to:

- instantiate a blank project?
- or instantiate something without so much code already written (e.g. see below)?
- or something that can customize the name of the app (i.e. if I named my Flutter Application hello_world, `MyApp` would be called `HelloWorld`?

Something like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new HelloWorld());

class HelloWorld extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with having the Counter boilerplate ?

Comment: I have to rename each of the classes and remove the boilerplate for stuff that I don't need (e.g. comments, floatingActionButton). Though, yes, I could just delete all the code and start from scratch. It would be nice if there was an option for that currently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, currently `flutter create` (and the new project wizards in the IDEs) only create that one example. That's useful in that there are fewer questions asked for new users, who may not have the context to answer a lot of framework questions up front. I think the template is also a good balance between having too much boilerplate code while still providing enough exposure to the framework to be a good pedagogical example.

It likely should borrow a bit of its name from the project name (i.e., `hello_world.dart` ==> a class name of `HelloWorld`). For suggestions like that, https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new is the best place to provide feedback.

Answer (score 6):

Congratulations, you can do it now (Flutter 3.7)
you can create an empty Flutter project (using the --empty parameter)
e.g.,
flutter create project_name --empty

Answer (score 5):

You can now do that by adding "**-e**" flag before the app name when creating a new project.

```
flutter create -e test_app
```

Answer (score 2):

This is possible now using the following command:

`flutter create  --sample=material.FloatingActionButton.1 my_demo_app`

Here `sample` can be given a value of a sample id. Some examples can be found at  [this link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-cli-52-hidden-samples-fc90f218a9d0) (Longer than Stackoverflow's answer limit so can't be copied here)

Answer (score 0):

If it truly is unbearable you could onetime create a project with only the bear minimum of items (one stateless widget) on it and delete all the the things you don’t want.

Clone this empty project every time you need it.
Or copy and paste it for visual studio in the place you want it.

This should work but I haven’t done it yet

Answer (score 0):

**IntelliJ**
[image: see how to do it image]

sample template for flutter

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:your_app/screens/home.dart';


void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Navigtion',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {

      },
      home: new Home(),
    );
  }
}
```

when you start build your project delete everything in main.dart and type your template abbreviation and hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new Test());

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container();
  }
}
```

The overrided widget is the route of your application